# How to resolve the error that comes when finding the toolbar view inside the activity layout(android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

**Toolbar** toolbar = (**Toolbar**) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

the bolded words(Toolbar)becomes red when it is added to the MainActivity.java file.

The error says(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar? (multiple choices...) Alt+Enter)

Comment: That's not quite an error. The IDE is helping you resolve a class to import

Answer (score 0):

just do it (Alt+Enter)

and it will import for you the right class

Comment: I pressed alt+enter then it showed two classes should i select android.support.v7.appcombat class

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is the way to go.

A drop down list should appear and then you just press **Import class**.

[image]